# Mobile data can't connect (with exclamation mark) but wifi

Tags: internet, mobile-data, network-signal

My phone is Motorola XT1033 dual-SIM (Lollipop 5.1)

- have active mobile-data internet packages
- can connect and open provider's website (to check package status & quota)
- valid APN settings (at least following provider's instructions)

There is a problem on mobile-data connection, see the differences here:

**Data ON, Wi-fi OFF**

[image]

- there is an exclamation mark on the mobile-data signal bar
- NOT connected to internet (even the signal is H)

**Data ON, Wi-fi ON**

[image]

- there is NO exclamation mark on the mobile-data signal bar
- connected to internet

What I've tried so far

- rebooting my phone
- turn mobile-data off and back on
- re-attach the SIM card
- install my SIM card to another handset (can't connect to internet)
- install another SIM card to mine (can connect to internet)

Does anyone have the same problem? I'm looking forward for the solution.

Comment: Have you tried switching to GSM only mode ? maybe the WCDMA network falling short in your locality.

Comment: @reachrk i just try it but it still not works